# Is there a way to delete a tag? Specifically [jodatimetime]

Tags: support, tags, tag-deletion

I was reviewing some SO edits today, and someone submitted an edit for the [jodatimetime] tag:

> This is a misspelling of tag "jodatime". Sorry I don't know the process to propose turning a tag into a synonym for another.

And indeed that tag has only 2 questions tagged.

I am going to go retag those 2 questions to [jodatime], but is there a process for cleaning up the [jodatimetime] tag?

Comment: It will be auto-deleted in a short while, by an automatic process.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already gotten rid of both questions tagged under it, so the tag will go away automatically within 24 hours. The tag wiki excerpt that was suggested has been rejected, as it should be. That tag wiki is completely useless, and their effort would have been better spent retagging the whole two questions that had the improper tag.

However, normally if a question has too many tags to pull off a manual retagging of all the questions, a request can be made on Meta and either the community will help you or the team will [burninate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request) the tag.